# how to restrict entering a 9 digit number in alpha numeric textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How to restrict user from entering a 9 digit number in alpha numeric textarea. the textarea can have alphabets. The textarea should allow all numbers except 9-digit numbers.

Comment: Can the users type in a 10 digit number?

Comment: Digits should be continuous or with gap? Add example of textbox value.

Comment: @viaz- yes. User can type 10-digit number,8-digit number etc

Comment: @Mohammad- digits should be continuous. eg.123456789- not allowed but 12345678,0123456789,3678456 are allowed.

Comment: As you said *can type 10-digit number*. But how you want to type digit with length 10 while you can't type length 9?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#txtName').keyup( function() {
         var str = $(this).val();
         var digits = str.replace(/\D/g, "##");
         var splitdigits = digits.split("##");
       if (splitdigits.length > 0)
       {
         for(var Icount = 0; Icount < splitdigits.length; Icount++)
         { 
          if (splitdigits[Icount] != '' && splitdigits[Icount].match(/^\d+$/) && splitdigits[Icount].length == 9)
            {

                 alert('Invalid input'); 
                 return false;
           }
        }
      }
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txtName" type="text" >
```

Use above code in script tag u can change "#txtName" and use your textarea id

Comment: @Anudeep- any 9 digit number should be treated as invalid

Comment: @anudeep- What i want is the content in textarea should have alphabets n everything except a 9-digit number. eg content in text area is: 1.bsdahcfbhsdchsdchsvbdchbsdhc 123456789- this should not be allowed      2.asdjbnsjdusdvcjsdnv dsvbsdhbv sdbnv*&%^$^&%^ 12365566- this should allowed as its a 8 digit number with text

Comment: @Saurabh Now i have changed to validate as per your query, it first removes non digits and put into a array and lopes the digits if it contains 9 digits it throws a alert. you can run code snippet for verification

Answer (score 0):

What trigger do you use to validate the textbox?
if is for submiting or a validate function, you can try

```
//regvalu can be ^[-+]?[1-9]\d*$(dont alow zero in from
///or ^\d+$ for any digit
var regex = new RegExp(regVal)
if($('#textBox').length == 9  && regex.test($('#textBox').text())
 {
    alert('Your value is invalid');
 }
```